# Apache Camel MyBatis :- 90-second timeout on delete

Tags: timeout, apache-camel, mybatis

It's adding a lot of time to the route and is quite an annoyance

It looks in source like the

```
from( ... ) 
.stuff()
.to( "mybatis:deleteTable?statementType=Delete" )
```

corresponding with

```
<delete id="deleteTable" parameterType="java.lang.Object" >
    delete from table;
</delete>
```

presumably it's waiting for a response with a 90-second timeout on the delete call and then carries on.

It's 90 seconds regardless of size of data in the table. whethre empty or actual records inside.

it sounds like its expecting a response that it doesn't get, and waiting for a timeout before carrying on.

It's very annoying and I cant find a work-around

looking in code this might be because it looks like the mybatis sql session implementation org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession delete(...) methods just delegate to the update(...) , which might be waiting for a response...

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the message coming to in was many thousands of messages in a List
 it was calling the delete once for each item in the list

you can get around it by setting the statementType=InsertList - which expects a simlar return to delete and passes List as a single object, not iterating over its contents